# Generic string to enum conversion

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose enum:

```
public enum SysLogsAppTypes { None, MonitorService, MonitorTool };
```

and here is a function to convert from the `ToString()` representation back to `enum`:

```
private SysLogsAppTypes Str2SysLogsAppTypes(string str)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        SysLogsAppTypes res = (SysLogsAppTypes)Enum
                                       .Parse(typeof(SysLogsAppTypes), str);  
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SysLogsAppTypes), res)) 
            return SysLogsAppTypes.None;  
        return res;  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
    return SysLogsAppTypes.None;  
    }  
}
```

Is there a way to make this Generic ??

I tried:

```
private T Str2enum<T>(string str)   
{  
    try  
    {  
        T res = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), str);  
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), res)) return T.None;  
        return res;  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        return T.None;  
    }  
}
```

but I get:
'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context
where there is T.None

Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: Just substitute `default(T)` for `T.None` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 19):

I think the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword is what you need:

```
private T Str2enum<T>(string str) where T : struct
{   
    try   
    {   
        T res = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), str);   
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), res)) return default(T);   
        return res;   
    }   
    catch   
    {   
        return default(T);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it's important to note that the "default" enum is whatever value is represented by 0.  This is usually the first value.  However, if your enum starts at 1, you will return `0` instead of any legal value in the enum.  Using this method would require a caveat for this behavior or some coding standard. For instance, I've seen some enums where a `NONE` value is the last value, which would not work in this method.

Answer (score 5):

Not the way you are trying it, but I use the method below to do this:

```
 public static bool EnumTryParse<E>(string enumVal, out E resOut) 
        where E : struct
 {
      var enumValFxd = enumVal.Replace(' ', '_');
      if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(E), enumValFxd))
      {
          resOut = (E)Enum.Parse(typeof(E), 
             enumValFxd, true);
          return true;
      }
      // ----------------------------------------
      foreach (var value in
          Enum.GetNames(typeof (E)).Where(value => 
              value.Equals(enumValFxd, 
              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
      {
          resOut = (E)Enum.Parse(typeof(E), value);
          return true;
      }
      resOut = default(E);
      return false;
 }
```

No exceptions thrown here ...

Comment: I love this solution.  I always prefer a TryParse over the assumption that values are legit.

Comment: +1 - I like the `TryParse` pattern, but a note: by doing the `Enum.IsDefined` method call before attempting to convert, this will fail to convert string representations of the underlying value of an `enum`. That's one benefit of the `try catch` and then check `Enum.IsDefined` algorithm. I suppose you could do an `int.TryParse` first and add a special case for that to the above solution.

Comment: @jball,  by " string representations of the underlying value ", are you talking about like, "1", "12", "one" or "two" or "TwentyThree" ??

Answer (score 4):

I like to add in a `defaultValue` parameter for an overload of my `TryParse` for cases where I want a default if it can't be parsed or is null. This is most useful for parsing `string.Empty` or `null`.

Note: this implementation will revert to `defaultValue` if a junk value is passed in - so you may want to tweak that by throwing an exception.

```
public static T TryParse<T>(string value, T defaultValue) where T: struct
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }

            T result;
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(value, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return defaultValue;  // you may want to throw exception here
            }
        }
    }


    ConverterMode mode = EnumUtils<ConverterMode>.TryParse(stringValue, ConverterMode.DefaultMode);
```

Comment: Love this version because I get to tell it what Enum/value to return if it fails, and not necessarily a 0 or other standard I must implement across all enums.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I don't throw an exception where I indicated here, but I think that would be a better approach

Comment: actually what i did after the `Enum.TryParse` was to check if it was defined with `Enum.IsDefined()`. If it wasn't, I also made it the default value. And i wouldn't want to throw an exception in here because it's a `Try`. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but based on a few samples, I've researched along with [@Simon_Weaver's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367497/286618) solution, this is what I have:

```
public static T TryParse(String value, T defaultValue) where T : struct {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    T result;
    if (!Enum.TryParse(value, out result)) {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof (T), result) | result.ToString().Contains(",")) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            result = defaultValue;
        }
    } else {
        result = defaultValue;
    }

    return result;
}
```